# Approximating linearly independent functions with linearly independent functions.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space.

Let $f_{1}, ... , f_{n}$ be an $\bf{\text{Auerbach basis}}$ for a finite dimensional subspace $N\subset L_{1} := L_{1}(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$.

That is, $\{f_{1},...,f_{n}\}$ is a basis for $N$ and the associated coordinate functionals $\{f^{*}_{1},...,f^{*}_{n}\}$ form a basis for $N^{*}$, and $\|f_{j}\| = \|f^{*}_{j}\| = 1$.

---

$\bf{\text{Question:}}$

For each $j=1,..., n$, choose an integrable simple function $g_{j}\in L_{1}$ with $\|f_{j} - g_{j}\|_{1} < \frac{\epsilon}{n^{2}}$.  Then $\{g_{1}, ... , g_{n}\}$ is linearly independent.  Why?

$\bf{\text{Edit:}}$ The above need not be true, as pointed out below by copper.hat.

(This issue arises in the proof that $L_{1}$ is a $\mathcal{L}_{1,1+\epsilon}$ space for all $\epsilon > 0$.)

---

$\bf{\text{My Ideas:}}$

If I suppose for some $\alpha_{1}, ... , \alpha_{n}$, not all equal to $0$, that $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}g_{j} = 0$, then 
$$\alpha_{j} = f_{j}^{*}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{k}f_{k}\right) = f_{j}^{*}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{k}(f_{k}-g_{k})\right)$$

By rescaling if necessary, I can assume that $\text{max}_{j=1}^{n}|\alpha_{j}| = 1$.

Therefore $|\alpha_{j}|\leq \|f_{j}^{*}\|\cdot \|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{k}(f_{k}-g_{k})\|_{1} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}|\alpha_{k}|\cdot \|f_{k} - g_{k}\|_{1} < \frac{\epsilon}{n}$.

This gives me $\|\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}f_{j}\|_{1} < \epsilon$.  If $\epsilon > 0$ were arbitrary, I could pass $\epsilon \to 0$ and be done, but the $g_{j}'s$ depend on $\epsilon$ so this is not valid.

Something that I have not used is that the $g_{j}$'s are simple functions.  If it were helpful, I could even take them to have compact support as such functions are dense in $L_{1}$.

---

I'm hoping for a hint if anyone knows how to prove this.

Thanks very much for your time in reading this.

Comment: What is the $f,g$ in the question? I presume by $g$ you meant $g_j$ and by $f$ you meant $f_j$?

Comment: I have no additional information about the $f_{j}$'s.

I'm thinking that the $g_{j}$'s might have to be more carefully chosen.  And yes I missed my indices.  I'll fix it right now.  :)

Comment: The author says, "It is easy to see that the $g_{j}$'s are linearly independent."

Comment: There must be some conditions on $\epsilon$. Otherwise you can choose any $g_i$ and set $\epsilon$ accordingly.

Comment: We are trying to show that $L_{1}$ is $\mathcal{L}_{1,1+\epsilon}$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.  So $\epsilon$ was chosen arbitrarily at the beginning.  Sorry, I forgot to bind $\epsilon$ in my statement of the problem.

Comment: If there is a concern that $\epsilon$ may be too large, it would not harm anything to shrink it to be as small as desired.  Because if $L_{1}$ is a $\mathcal{L}_{1,1+\epsilon}$ space, it is automatically a $\mathcal{L}_{1,1+\delta}$ space for any $\delta > \epsilon$.  Does that help?

Comment: I see what you are getting at now.  It seems like there needs to be some condition on $\epsilon$ otherwise there is no reason to expect the $g_j$'s to be independent.

Comment: I now think the proof is just wrong.  Maybe there is a quick fix.  I'll think about it some more before posting back.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: All that is needed is insist that $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small so that whenever $g_{j}$ gets within $\epsilon/n^{2}$ of $f_{j}$, we have linear independence of the $g_{j}$'s.  The $\epsilon/n^{2}$ part is used later in the proof.  I just need to figure out how small $\epsilon$ needs to be now.

Comment: I think I can just take, for each $j = 1,..., n$, a sequence of integrable simple functions $g^{j}_{n}$ converging in norm to $f_{j}$.  If I assume for a contradition that for every fixed $n$, the $g^{j}_{n}$'s are linearly dependent, I should get a contradiction.  I will attempt to sort out the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\gamma: \mathbb{R}^n \times (L^1)^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by  $\gamma(\alpha, \phi) = \|\sum_k \alpha_k \phi_k \|_1$. Clearly $\phi$ is continuous in the product space (that is, let $\|(\alpha, \phi) \| = \|\alpha\| + \sum_k \|\phi_k\|_1$).

Let $\eta(\phi) = \min_{\| \alpha \| = 1} \gamma(\alpha, \phi)$. A little work shows that $\eta$ is continuous. Furthermore, $\eta(\phi) = 0$ **iff** the $\phi_1,...,\phi_n$ are linearly dependent.

We have $\eta(f) \neq 0$, hence for some neighborhood $U$ of $f$ (in the space $(L^1)^n$), we have $\eta(\phi) \neq 0$ whevever $\phi \in U$.

Comment: I still wasn't able to solve it on my own ,so I really appreciate this.  But isn't $\eta(f) = 0?$, since $f_{1},...,f_{n}$ *are* linearly independent?

Comment: No, if $\eta(f) = 0$, this means that for some non zero $\alpha$ you have $\sum_k \alpha_k f_k = 0$. Since the $f$ are linearly independent, we must have $\eta(f) > 0$.

Comment: This is essentially the fact that if a matrix has trivial kernel, then so do nearby matrices.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your second sentence when I asked that.

Thanks very much this is great.

Comment: You are very welcome. Your question was interesting and broadened my understanding.

Comment: Showing continuity of $\eta$ was harder than I thought.  The proof is on Willie Wong's blog and can be found here: http://williewong.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/continuity-of-the-infimum/
for anyone else who finds this answer useful.

Comment: It is a useful tool to have in your arsenal. If you are dealing with metric spaces (or any first countable), then a proof using sequences is straightforward (I prefer proofs that don't rely in sequences, but they are frequently more straightforward).